# Multiple Date rows into One single Date row(date range)

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql, sql-server-2016

An employee was sick during different period of time, when there is not a single day difference between the multiple dates range, or the date is continuous then it should be shown in one row covering all period of that range. But as soon there is a difference of more than one day between previous row TOdate and next row FromDate, which means that the employee worked and that whole period should be considered one period with one row to display. Please refer to following excel sheet .I include a sample data as well which is as follow;

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Absent](
    [EmpNr] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [CompCode] [varchar](3)NOT Null,
    [PaymentDate] [varchar](8)Not Null,
    [FromDate] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [ToDate] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [TotalDays] [numeric](38, 2) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Absent]
VALUES
(800334,301,20210225,20210111,20210111, -1.00),
(800334,302,20210225,20210114,20210114, -1.00),
(800334,301,20210423,20210214,20210214, 1.00 ),
(800334,301,20210325,20210214,20210214, -1.00),
(800334,302,20210423,20210214,20210214, -1.00),
(800334,301,20210423,20210309,20210309, -1.00),
(800334,302,20210423,20210312,20210312, -1.00),
(800334,301,20210525,20210407,20210407, -1.00),
(800334,302,20210525,20210408,20210412, -5.00),
(800334,302,20210525,20210414,20210420, -7.00),
(800334,301,20210525,20210511,20210511, -1.00),
(800334,302,20210525,20210512,20210524, -13.00),
(800334,304,20210525,20210525,20210531, -7.00),
(800334,304,20210624,20210601,20210606, -6.00),
(800334,301,20210924,20210820,20210820, -1.00),
(800334,302,20210924,20210825,20210825, -1.00),
(800334,301,20211025,20210910,20210910, -1.00),
(800334,302,20211025,20210911,20210915, -5.00),
(800761,302,20201223,20201112,20201117, -6.00),
(800761,301,20210125,20201214,20201214, -1.00),
(800761,302,20210125,20201215,20201223, -9.00),
(800761,301,20201223,20201111,20201111, -1.00),
(800761,301,20210225,20210120,20210120, -1.00),
(800761,302,20210225,20210121,20210122, -2.00),
(800761,301,20210325,20210211,20210211, -1.00),
(800761,301,20211125,20211018,20211018, -1.00),
(800761,302,20211125,20211019,20211031, -13.00),
(800341,301,20201125,20201022,20201022, -1.00) ,
(800341,302,20201125,20201023,20201025, -3.00) ,
(800341,301,20201223,20201103,20201103, -1.00) ,
(800341,302,20201223,20201104,20201104, -1.00) ,
(800341,301,20201223,20201119,20201119, -1.00) ,
(800341,302,20201223,20201120,20201129, -10.00),
(800341,301,20210125,20201217,20201217, -1.00) ,
(800341,302,20210125,20201218,20201230, -13.00),
(800341,301,20210225,20210111,20210111, -1.00) ,
(800341,302,20210225,20210112,20210124, -13.00),
(800341,304,20210225,20210125,20210131, -7.00) ,
(800341,304,20210225,20210201,20210207, -7.00) ,
(800341,304,20210225,20210208,20210221, -14.00),
(800341,304,20210225,20210222,20210228, -7.00) ,
(800341,304,20210325,20210222,20210228, 7.00)  ,
(800341,304,20210325,20210222,20210228, -7.00) ,
(800341,301,20210423,20210301,20210301, 1.00)  ,
(800341,301,20210325,20210301,20210301, -1.00) ,
(800341,304,20210423,20210301,20210314, -14.00),
(800341,302,20210325,20210302,20210314, -13.00),
(800341,302,20210423,20210302,20210314, 13.00) ,
(800341,301,20210525,20210408,20210408, -1.00) ,
(800341,302,20210525,20210409,20210421, -13.00),
(800341,305,20210525,20210422,20210430, -9.00) ,
(800341,305,20210624,20210501,20210514, -14.00),
(800341,305,20210624,20210504,20210514, -11.00),
(800341,305,20210624,20210515,20210531, -17.00),
(800341,305,20210723,20210601,20210630, -30.00),
(800341,305,20210825,20210701,20210731, -31.00),
(800341,305,20210924,20210801,20210815, -15.00),
(800341,305,20210924,20210816,20210831, -16.00),
(800341,305,20211025,20210901,20210905, -5.00) ,
(800341,305,20211025,20210906,20210923, -18.00),
(800341,305,20211025,20210929,20210930, -2.00) ,
(800341,305,20211125,20211001,20211003, -3.00) ,
(800341,305,20211125,20211004,20211025, -22.00),
(800341,305,20211125,20211026,20211026, -1.00 ),
(800341,305,20211125,20211027,20211031, -5.00) ,
(800341,302,20211220,20211201,20211215, -15.00)
```

[image]

/Thanks
Skiper

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please [edit] your question to show your expected output as text, not an image, and include your attempts.

Comment: I tried this following code  but its not fully worked
SELECT 
       f.empnr,
    f.FromDate ,
       min(s.ToDate) AS ToDate ,
    sum(f.totaldays) as TDays
FROM [dbo].[Result] f 

INNER JOIN 

[dbo].[Result] s ON 

f.FromDate <= s.ToDate 

AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Result] f1 
                 WHERE  s.ToDate >= f1.FromDate
                   AND s.ToDate < f1.ToDate) 

WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Result] s1
                 WHERE f.FromDate > s1.FromDate
                   AND f.FromDate <= s1.ToDate) 
GROUP BY f.Empnr,f.FromDate   
ORDER BY f.empnr